# Very weird behavior using sed

Tags: bash, replace, sed, character-encoding

I have a big problem doing a script: basically, I read a line from files.
All lines are made of 3 to 8 characters contiguous (no space).
Then I used sed to replace those lines inside a pattern (aka "var" in my minimal script below)

```
var="iao"
for m in `more meshing/junction_names.txt`
do 
    echo $m 
    echo -n $m  | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\x&/g'
    echo $var |sed "s/a/b/"
    echo $var |sed "s/a/$m/"
done
```

Now these are the first 3 record of my output (they are all the same anyway). 
I am using linux. According kate, all files are encoded UTF-8. Very weird huh? Any idea why that is is welcome.

```
J_LEAK 
\x4a\x5f\x4c\x45\x41\x4b\x0d
ibo
oJ_LEAK
JO_1
\x4a\x4f\x5f\x31\x0d
ibo
oJO_1
JPL2_F
\x4a\x50\x4c\x32\x5f\x46\x0d
ibo
oJPL2_F
JF_PL2
```

Comment: For a start, I'd recommend using `while read -r m` ... `done < meshing/junction_names.txt` instead of your `for` loop. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Hesitantly upvoting for the exemplary diagnostics you included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file contains DOS carriage returns (or possibly, the absurd attempt to read it with `more` introduces them).  The hex dump shows this clearly; every value ends with `\x0d` which translates to a control code which causes the terminal to jump the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

This is a massive FAQ and you can find many examples of how to troubleshoot this basic problem, including in the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Tangentially, you should always quote strings unless you specifically require the shell to perform wildcard expansion and whitespace tokenization on the value; and Bash has built-ins to avoid the inelegant and somewhat error-prone `echo | sed`.  Finally, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

```
var="iao"
tr -d '\015' <meshing/junction_names.txt |
while read -r m; do  # don't use a for loop
    echo "$m"        # quote! 
    echo -n "$m"  | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\x&/g'
    echo "${var/a/b}" # quote; use Bash built-in substitution mechanism
    echo "${var/a/$m}"
done
```

Perhaps you want to remove the carriage returns once and for all, and then just use `while read .... done <fixed-file` instead of the `tr` pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for carriage return, that was indeed the problem. So far as while loop is concerned, I will carry on using my odd for stuff. In 2015 I definitly expected to be able to no waste my time with the burden of local variables inside the while loop and every problem associated...